# Sort Aggregation in elastic seach?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, dsl, querydsl, elk

I have use case where I need to get all unique user ids from Elasticsearch and it should be sorted by timestamp.

What I'm using currently is composite term aggregation with sub aggregation which will return the latest timestamp.

(I can't sort it in client side as it slow down the script)

Sample data in elastic search

```
{
  "_index": "logstash-2020.10.29",
  "_type": "doc",
  "_id": "L0Urc3UBttS_uoEtubDk",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "@version": "1",
    "@timestamp": "2020-10-29T06:56:00.000Z",
    "timestamp_string": "1603954560",
    "search_query": "example 3",
    "user_uuid": "asdfrghcwehf",
    "browsing_url": "https://www.google.com/search?q=example+3",
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      "2020-10-29T06:56:00.000Z"
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1603954560000
  ]
}
```

Expected Output:

```
[
        {
          "key" : "bjvexyducsls",
          "doc_count" : 846,
          "1" : {
            "value" : 1.603948557E12,
            "value_as_string" : "2020-10-29T05:15:57.000Z"
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "lhmsbq2osski",
          "doc_count" : 420,
          "1" : {
            "value" : 1.6039476E12,
            "value_as_string" : "2020-10-29T05:00:00.000Z"
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "m2wiaufcbvvi",
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "1" : {
            "value" : 1.603893635E12,
            "value_as_string" : "2020-10-28T14:00:35.000Z"
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "rrm3vd5ovqwg",
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "1" : {
            "value" : 1.60389362E12,
            "value_as_string" : "2020-10-28T14:00:20.000Z"
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "x42lk4t3frfc",
          "doc_count" : 72,
          "1" : {
            "value" : 1.60389318E12,
            "value_as_string" : "2020-10-28T13:53:00.000Z"
          }
        }
      ]
```

Comment: can you please provide some sample index data, mapping, and expected search query results? Do you have a `date` field in your sample index data?

Comment: added the sample data question. need something like sorted list of aggregation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a working example with index data, mapping, search query, and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings":{
    "properties":{
      "user":{
        "type":"keyword"
      },
      "date":{
        "type":"date"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "date": "2015-01-01",
  "user": "user1"
}
{
  "date": "2014-01-01",
  "user": "user2"
}
{
  "date": "2015-01-11",
  "user": "user3"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "user_id": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "user",
        "order": {
          "sort_user": "asc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sort_user": {
          "min": {
            "field": "date"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"aggregations": {
    "user_id": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "user2",
          "doc_count": 1,
          "sort_user": {
            "value": 1.3885344E12,
            "value_as_string": "2014-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "user1",
          "doc_count": 1,
          "sort_user": {
            "value": 1.4200704E12,
            "value_as_string": "2015-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "user3",
          "doc_count": 1,
          "sort_user": {
            "value": 1.4209344E12,
            "value_as_string": "2015-01-11T00:00:00.000Z"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: @Sanker please go through my answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?

Comment: sure thanks... ! What if I have 10k + users ... ? can I use it with composite aggregation or any kind of pagination option available??

Comment: @Sanker I think you can use Composite Aggregation as it allows pagination within aggregated results, to know more about this you can refer to this https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.9/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html

Comment: thanks I'll. but what I understood is composite aggregation with sorting is not possible...
anyway I'll have a try and update.

Comment: Hello, I wrote an article on pagination for aggregation. I hope it could help https://spoon-elastic.com/all-elastic-search-post/pagination-aggregation-elasticsearch/

Comment: sure I'll check it out

Comment: @Jaycreation that was indeed a great article  , if you liked my answer, then please don't forget to upvote my answer as well 

Comment: don't worry Bhavya upvote your answer was the first thing I did ;)

Comment: @Sanker if my answer helped you resolve your issue, then please don't forget to upvote and accept my answer , and please go through my other answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64590969/10348758, to your new question

Comment: @Sanker any update and luck here? Would be great if you can upvote and accept my answer if it helped you :)